# How to execute Run function before any controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to make my first application, I want to the run function to be executed before any controller.

My run function looks like :

```
.run(function ($rootScope,authentification) 
{    

teamsFactory.sendAuthent().then(function(response) 
{    
$rootScope.authentdata=response.data;
    });
})
```

My service where I make the authentication :

```
 teams.sendAuthent= function(DeviceID) {  
    return $http({method:"POST",url:http://myserver.com/authentification",headers: {'X-SocialAPI-Service-Name': 'auth'}})
    .then(function(aResponse)
    {
    var deferred=$q.defer();
    deferred.resolve({data:aResponse.data});
    return deferred.promise;   
    }); 
    }
```

And this is my controller where I use the rootScope data :

```
.controller('home', function($rootScope,$scope, $http,) 
{



     alert($rootScope.authentdata.token);



})
```

But this is not working it says that autehndata is undefined, so the controller is executed before the run function how to resolve that ?

Comment: `run` block of angular execute only once when `config` phase is done

Comment: In my case it executes after my controller

Comment: just watch the rootscope value and when it's defined and usable make your function call.

Comment: @z.a. can you provide an example please ! thanks

Comment: Your code likely IS running in the correct order, you just aren't waiting for the asynchronous request to complete. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this,

```
$rootScope.$watch('authentdata', function(n, o) {
    if(angular.isDefined(n) {
        alert($rootScope.authentdata.token);
        // or alert(n.token);
    }
}
```